# With 'autoload' being deprecated, what should devs use in the meantime?

Tags: ruby, autoload

Having read a couple weeks ago that `autoload` is [officially deprecated](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/5653), Matz discourages use of it.  What is to replace it?  What should developers do instead?  I used it in some command-line gems to save unnecessary loading of libs that may never be used, as well as in JRuby to prevent the same for `.jar` files.

Comment: You could ask on the thread you linked.

Comment: The link is dead, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.  Found an even better link to use instead!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen people use the [EasyLoad](http://rubygems.org/gems/easyload) gem, it claims to be a `autoload` alternative.  It loads based on directory module naming convention.

Comment: As the author of easyload; I haven't touched it in a very long time.  If there's renewed interest, I'd love to hand it off to a more active maintainer

Comment: I have great interest in EasyLoad, I'm currently writing a library for interacting with various shipping carriers and I have been debating using EasyLoad for that, I would be more than happy to maintain it. Thanks.

Comment: Ping me on github; let's figure out the best way to transition the repo & gem

Comment: If Easyload was the replacement for ruby's autoload, why is its first instruction a call to autoload?

Comment: @PabloMarambio - Good point.  It looks like that's the only use of autoload, and it's just loading a version file.  I think it will be trivial for the gem's maintainer to change, when autoload finally goes away (although it really out to be done sooner).

Comment: @WayneConrad - When I get a second, I'll look at it and make the modifications to remove the autoload call.